# Automated CSV upload to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgis

I would like to ask if it´s possible to update a CSV with daily data (temperature, pressure, humidity, etc.. ) to PostgreSQL as a scheduled task.

I´d like to create a new table every time with format YYYYMMDD which can be uploaded automatically as a scheduled task on PostgreSQL.

I´ve seen there is a function called PGagent which I have installed but not sure about the use.

Many thanks

Comment: `I´d like to create a new table every time with ...` Why? What is the use of having a lot of tables with exactly the same structure?

Comment: Just to hold the monthly data, but if it´s not possible it will work for me just overwrite each time the same table with the same attributes but changing only time-stamp. Thanks

Comment: Why not add/append the new data, growing the table with every import?

Comment: Thanks wildplasser, I think that can be the idea, add new data to the table, but I still need an automated thing/script? that can upload automatically a CSV file to PostgreSQL every day.

Comment: You can automate that, either with cron(if you happen to live on Unix) or with something like PgAgent.

Comment: I think that might be the question, how to update database through PgAgent, any idea might be good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just write some simple script using [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) statement and run it via psql+cron or pgagent.